# Selenium clicking button only some of the times

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



Countries = ['Australia', 'India', 'America', 'France', 'Croatia', 'Portugal', 'Pakistan']
keyword = ""
slash = '/'


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path to chromedriver",)

for country in Countries:
    driver.get('https://www.pexels.com/search/' + country + keyword + slash)  

    clickimg = driver.find_element_by_class_name("photo-item__img")
    clickimg.click()

    alt = clickimg.get_attribute('alt')

    download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'js-download-a-tag rd__button')]")

    download.click()
```

I am new to Selenium and Python and was making an app which downloads the first image of the `country` in `Countries` on [pexels](https://www.pexels.com/). Everything works except the download button. The issue I am having with `download.click()` is that sometimes when I run the program it works and other times it doesn't. I will really appreciate if someone can help with this problem.

[It is not working currently but was working flawlessly an hour ago. Same thing happened yesterday.]

I have also tried:-

```
 download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-id='68704']")
```

This one only works for Australia as the other countries have different ids (I checked using inspect element)

```
download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'rd__button-group rd__button-group--space-with-margin-left')]//a)[1]")
```

This one doesn't work

Comment: Although not an answer, you can use their API. It would be much easier, faster and there would be no chances of getting your public IP banned.
https://www.pexels.com/api/

Answer (score 0):

Three things you can try after "alt = clickimg.get_attribute('alt')"

1. Add a sleep time of one second.
2. Use the full XPATH for the button.
3. Check the terminal and share with us what exception you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used `time.sleep()` and it didn't work. I also tried using implicit wait as shown in Nikhil's answer.

As for the full XPath, I am using a _XPATH Finder_ and I have tried all the codes they have shown. I will really appreciate if you can help with finding the full XPATH of the button

This is the error I am getting: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

(nothing special)

Answer (score 0):

As popup will take time to load so you have to explicit wait your code. Please try below code. Its worked for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



Countries = ['Australia', 'India', 'America', 'France', 'Croatia', 'Portugal', 'Pakistan']
keyword = ""
slash = '/'


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for country in Countries:
    driver.get('https://www.pexels.com/search/' + country + keyword + slash)

    clickimg = driver.find_element_by_class_name("photo-item__img")
    clickimg.click()

    alt = clickimg.get_attribute('alt')

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'js-download-a-tag rd__button')]")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    download.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

I am still getting this error: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

Is there a problem with my IDE? I am using _PyCharm_ so I don't think there should be.

Comment: once i run the code as i shared with you its downloaded a image is this expected result? I am using the VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I see that based on your error, you are not waiting enough time for the element to become available or appear. Use this code below to make the driver wait until the element becomes available or timeout. In the example below I am waiting 120 seconds for it to timeout or move forward after it locates the element.

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH,
         '/html/body/div[13]/div[1]/ul/li[12]/div/div[3]'))
)
```

Check the selenium "Explicit Waits" for more options: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Let me know if that works.